# Display thumbnails that link to full-size image in a lightbox (without two separate image files)

Tags: jquery, css, image, lightbox, lightbox2

I am displaying a number images in the standard HTML format. I don't know the size of the image. Some are small in size, but others are quite large.

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
```

What I'd like to do..

1. Scale the images down without distorting it (if wider or taller than 250px x 250px).
2. The user should be able to click on the image to view the full-size in a lightbox.

I saw the [lightbox jQuery plug-in](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), but it seems to require separate thumbnail images. Is there a way to still take advantage of that?

I'm using the latest Chrome, so I can use HTML5/CSS3/jQuery/etc for this project.

Comment: you should have two images, but if you load the image and want a smaller version you could just do `<img src="abc.jpg" width=50 height=50>`, but the user has to load the whole image( a lot of data for a thumbnail image)

Comment: This isn't even a question. Everything except for scaling images can be done with lightbox, take some time to read the manual if you don't know how.

Comment: jonathan, the question is that i'm wondering if i can use lightbox without separate thumbnail images. i read the manual and it did not seem possible, but thought i would ask. is that not legitimate on stackoverflow? i'm a bit new here so apologies if so.

Answer (score 3):

A few advices:

Whenever you have to deal with thumbnails/full scale images, you have to provide **both** because using full image as previews impacts overall loading performance [think about mobile devices].

If you have control on the server, consider using some **on demand scaling** [e.g. [GD library in PHP]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) or **preemptive caching of thumbnails** [better and more scalable option].

One last thing: about *you* using Chrome, consider there would be people stuck with **IE8** or so, think about the audience of your website and not only your testing environment then.